# I'm programming sorting algorithm - Shellsort. Where is bug?

Tags: algorithm, shell, sorting, shellsort

I'm programming sorting algorithm — Shellsort. Where is bug?

```
int shellsort( int ai_numbers[], const int ci_count ){

    int i, j, temp, counter = 0, inc;
    inc = ci_count / 2;

    while ( inc > 0 )
    {
        for ( i = inc + 1; i < ci_count ; i++)
        {
            temp = ai_numbers[i];
            j = i;

            while ( j > inc && ai_numbers[j - inc] > temp )
            {
                ai_numbers[j] = ai_numbers[j - inc];
                j = j - inc;
                counter++;
            }
            ai_numbers[j] = temp;
        }

        inc = (int) (inc / 2.2);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what errors you are getting?

Comment: I have this array: int ai_numbers[] = { 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0 }; and I need this int ai_numbers[] = { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 }; but result is int ai_numbers[] = { 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };

Comment: Note: the `int i, j, ... , inc;` line shadows the (global?) `inc` you assigned to on the line above.

Comment: No, but is other bug. I was editing again. I have problem which I have this array { 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 0 } so result is { 100, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 }; Somewhere is bug but I dont know where is(

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the inner loop,

```
while ( j > inc && ai_numbers[j - inc] > temp )
```

causes the algorithm to never even look at `ai_numbers[0]`. The algorithm seems to be written with 1-based array indices in mind.

The loop controls should be

```
for ( i = inc; i < ci_count ; i++)
```

and

```
while ( j >= inc && ai_numbers[j - inc] > temp )
```

to properly incorporate `ai_numbers[0]`.